# Introduction to statistics

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$. Find a function $f$ such that $Y=f(X)$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $1$. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need $\Pr(f(X)\le y) = 1-e^{-y}$ for $y>0$.  That is true if $f$ is an increasing function and $\Pr(X\le f^{-1}(y))=1-e^{-y}$.  But you know that $\Pr(X\le x)=(x-a)/(b-a)$ if $a\le x\le b$, so $\Pr(X\le f^{-1}(y))=(f^{-1}(y)-a)/(b-a)$.  Thus it is enough to find a fuunction $f$ for which
$$
\frac{f^{-1}(y)-a}{b-a} = 1-e^{-y}\text{ for }y\ge 0. 
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Is it true if $f$ is decreasing?

Comment: @mookid : Actually there are both increasing and decreasing functions, and non-monotonic functions that can serve, because instead of using the fact that $\Pr(X\le x)=(x-z)/(b-a)$, we could have used the fact that $\Pr(X\ge \text{a certain number})=(x-a)/(b-a)$, or that $\Pr(X\in\text{a certain other set})=(x-a)/(b-a)$.

Comment: my point being, if $f$ is not increasing, there is no equivalence between $f(X)\le y$ and $X\le f^ {-1}(y)$

Comment: OK, I've revised my answer.  For convenience, it now rules out non-increasing functions that would also serve.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
you know that $$
a<x<b\implies P(X>x) = \frac{b-x}{b-a}
$$and you want
$$
P(f(X)>y) = e^{-y}$$

**solution:**
assuming that $f$ is one to one and increasing,
$$
e^{-y}=P(f(X)>y) = P(X > f^{-1}(y)) = \frac{b-f^{-1}(y)}{b-a}
\\
f^{-1}(y) = b-(b-a)e^{-y}
$$
And solve for $y=f(x)$:
$$
x=f^{-1}(y) = b-(b-a)e^{-y}\\
f(x) = y=-\log\frac{b-x}{b-a}
$$

Eventually, check that $f$ is one to one and increasing.